# Formulating an Equation for the sum of some functions

Tags: summation, network

I am trying to calculate the sum of percentages of some groups:

the network is composed of groups of networks, each group is composed of nodes, I am calculating the percentage of few nodes in the group. So imagine Group1 has ($N = 20$ nodes) and I want to calculate the percentage of some of the nodes over the total number of the nodes, it will be something like this ($y_1 = x_1$ / $N = 2$ nodes / $20$ nodes $= 0.1$) where $y_1$ is the percentage of $x_1 / N$ for Group 1 , now I need to formulate a mathematical equation that represents the sum of percentages of many groups (i.e: Group 1, Group 2,... Group $m$). The $1$ in $y_1$ and $x_1$ represents that they belong to Group 1. And I want to calculate Ytotal which is the sum of $y_1 + y_2 + \ldots + y(m)$.

Can anyone help?